# What is the expected value of two independent events occurring?

Tags: probability

Assume we have two independent events which are not mutually exclusive, A and B.  Assume that the probability of event A occurring is 70%, and 50% for event B.  Also assume that the impact of event A occurring is 120 while the impact of B occurring is 90.
The probability of either A or B occurring is:  P(A or B) = 70% + 50% - 70%*50% = 85%.
The expected value of the impact if A occurs is:  EVI(A) = 70%*120 = 84.
The expected value of the impact if B occurs is:  EVI(B) = 50%*90 = 45.
On average, what is the value of the impact if A or B occur?

Is it 85%*(84+45) = 109.65, or is it 95.65?  The latter figure is obtained via a small program with many iterations (e.g. 10M) as:  impactAorBTotalExpectedValue / countAorB, where if A or B occurs, A or B's expected value is added to impactAorBTotalExpectedValue, and countAorB is incremented once.

P(A) = 70%
P(B) = 50%
I(A) = 120
I(B) = 90
P(A or B) = 85%
EVI(A or B) = ?

Comment: It rather depends on what the impact is if both $A$ and $B$ occur.  And whether the $80$ and $120$ impacts are for when one occurs but not the other.

Comment: Assume that their individual impacts do not change if both events occur.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what the question actually means, the solution might be to look at:

- Neither occur: probability $0.15$, impact $0$
- A occurs but not B: probability $0.35$, impact $120$
- B occurs but not A: probability $0.15$, impact $90$
- Both occur: probability $0.35$, impact $120+90=210$

Expected impact given A or B occur: $\dfrac{0.35\times 120+0.15\times 90+0.35\times 210}{0.35+0.15+0.35}$